# Python - Appending data to a file, Line.split

Tags: python

In Python, I have a task to create a completely new file for storing high scores. The program should ask to enter your name, date and high score. **Each value should be separated by a comma.**

Here is my current code :

```
Name=input('What is your name:')
Date=input('What is the date:')
Score=input('What was your high score:')

myFile=open('Scores.txt','wt')
myFile.write(Name)
myFile.write(Date)
myFile.write(Score)
myFile.close()

myFile=open('Scores.txt','r')
line=myFile.readline()
line=line.split(',')
myFile.close()
```

I am having problems trying to separate each value by using a comma. What am I doing wrong? In the text file, the comma is not added, therefore all the values are next to eachother.

Thanks

Comment: You never write the commas to the file, bah!

Comment: `myFile.write("{},{},{}".format(Name, Date, Score))` or better yet, use [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: File mode should be `w+` not `wt`.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much! I was in need of this! It worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like so, you just have a few minor errors:

```
Name=input('What is your name:')
Date=input('What is the date:')
Score=input('What was your high score:')

myFile=open('Scores.txt','w+') # w+ not wt
myFile.write(Name + ',')
myFile.write(Date + ',')
myFile.write(Score)
myFile.close()

myFile=open('Scores.txt','r')
line=myFile.readline()
line=line.split(',') # commas need to be added to split
myFile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

More compact version:

```
Name=input('What is your name:')
Date=input('What is the date:')
Score=input('What was your high score:')

with open('Scores.txt','w+') as f:
    f.write(','.join([Name, Date, Score]))

with open('Scores.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = line.split(',')
```

**with** statement will automatically close the file.